# Why is `super` not resolved in the expected order?

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment, local-variables

I have this class hierarchy:

```
class Parent
    attr_accessor :params
    def initialize
        @params = {"original" => "original"}
    end
end

class Child < Parent
    def params
        super
    end

    def update_params_1
        params = {"update" => "update"}
        params
    end

    def update_params_2
        temp_var = params
        params = temp_var.merge({"update" => "update"})
        params
    end

    def update_params_3
        params = params.merge({"update" => "update"})
        params
    end
end

child = Child.new
child.update_params_1
# => {"update"=>"update"}
child.update_params_2
# => {"original"=>"original", "update"=>"update"}
child.update_params_3
# => undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

In `update_params_3`, `params` is `nil`.

I thought `params` might always be `nil` when involved in a method call on the RHS of an assignment operator. But that is not true. I added this method to verify that Ruby allows adding methods to the chain on the RHS. It works as expected.

```
def right_hand_side
    temp_var = params.inspect
    puts temp_var
end
```

Why does Ruby not resolve the `params` call in `update_params_3` before chaining the call to `merge`? Why is `params` `nil` only in the case where I assign a value to `params`? Is this intended or a bug in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because a local variable `params` is created and initialized as `nil` right after `params = ...` is parsed before or it or `params.merge({"update" => "update"})` is executed.

Since local variables have precedence over methods, the `params` in `params.merge({"update" => "update"})` is interpreted as the newly created local variable `params` instead of the method `params`.

Comment: Hm seems kind of obvious once you've told me the answer... now I feel dumb.

Answer (score 1):

`params = ...` assigns to a local variable called `params`. At no point do you actually modify `@params`, you just create a local variable called `params` and return it.

You need `self.params = ...` in every case where you're performing assignment if you intend to use the `params=` accessor on `self`.